# Competition in Google Keword tool

Tags: seo, search-engine

I am new to SEO, I am currently in the phase of finding keywords.
So I am using google keyword tool,

I am not quite sure what the Competition column indicates precisely .

If it says Low, high or medium what should I infer from it from SEO perspective?

Thanks, 
Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Competition column in Google keyword tool shows that number of advertisers bidding on that particular keywords. More competition means more advertisers targeting those keywords through Google adwords.

Find more details here : https://support.google.com/adwords/agency/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25148

Answer (score 0):

First choose keywords which u want to give services to visitor ... example.. Your website is php services than first choose php keyword.. don't mind if u choose that but just u see which keywords u take... how much compitition of that keywords? and if u have some problem to find keyword than suggestion from keyword tool.. there r lots of result which u help..

### Which keyword choose from suggestion?

Two types of keyword result first is local and second is global.. and three types of keyword competition low, medium and high. Don't choose looking low, medium and high.. just look to global and local competition..

### How much time for keyword result?

depends on keyword competition, your keyword competition high means lots of competitor than your keyword take a more time.

### Relevant keyword

I suggest u first that choose relevant keywords which keyword on title, description, content, hyperlink, image.. etc.